# Prove lower bound using decision tree comparison based model

Tags: algorithm, search, complexity-theory, clrs

How would you use a decision tree to prove that searching a sorted list of n elements has the lower bound Omega(log n) with the comparison based model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to use a decision tree...

For a given length **n**, the behaviour of a comparison-based algorithm can be represented as a decision tree wherein each leaf is the result you get after the sequence of comparisons and results represented by the path to that leaf.

You have prove that, in a decision tree with **n** leaves and a branching factor of **3**, the longest path to a leaf must have at least **ceil(log_3(n))** internal nodes.

You would prove this inductively, demonstrating that it is so for **n in {1,2,3}**, and that implies it is true for all greater **n**, because if a node's subtree has **n** leaves, then one of its children needs to have at least **n/3** leaves.

Comment: That really helps! Would you please elaborate on how you would prove it inductively? It's not that clear to me yet. Really appreciate you taking the time to answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the lower bound for the search problem has to be at least as large as the problem  of finding an entry in a sorted array, assuming the entry is already there. To solve this new problem, represent the relevant information you have as a node in your tree, concretely a node is the set of indexes in which your value  might lie. Initially, your value could correspond to any of the indexes, so your root would be {0, 1, ....,n}.

Whenever you do a comparison, because the array is sorted there are three possible outcomes: either the value you are looking for is greater than the one you have compared it to, or it is less than the value, or equal to it, so you have split your possible index set in three. Your algorithm solves the problem when the current node represents a singleton set, and the number of comparisons corresponds to the height of the tree.

The tree which splits the tree into n singleton leaves of minimal height is order log(n) and so that is the lower bound for any algorithm.